# Is it possible to monitor multiple bands from a single app?

Tags: microsoft-band

Is it possible to have one app on the android or ios phone monitor 2 or more bands, Place tiles and respond to button/ accelerometer events? I did not see that in the docs.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is possible. It is a more advanced configuration so you must pair the Band's in the phone's BlueTooth Settings. Then when you query the SDK APIs for devices you iterate over the devices and create one connection per device. This should allow you to then communicate with each device from within one app.